# Javaで配列の要素を逆順で出力したい

Tags: java

Java初心者です。学校の課題でJavaの配列に取り組んでいます。
とりあえず、配列内にキーボードで入力値を入れるところまでできたのですが、
イメージとは違うようです。

ユーザが入力した値を配列に入れ、最後に配列内の値を逆順で出力するプログラムです。
イメージとしては、以下のような感じです。

プロンプトとユーザからの入力:

```
整数を入力してください
3
2
1
```

出力結果:

```
1
2
3
```

ソースコードにおいて誤ってる箇所などありましたら指摘いただけるとありがたいです。

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // 配列sの初期化
    int[] s = new int[10];
    // 入力を10回受け付ける
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length-1; i++) {
        System.out.println("整数を入力してください");
        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        s[i] = scan1.nextInt();
        System.out.println(s[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: 説明が不十分です。`整数を入力してください`と表示してから、ユーザーの入力を3回受け付けると、入力の順序を逆にして表示するというプログラムですか？

Comment: 前提となる操作、期待される出力結果、現在のコードでの出力結果などを明確にしていないために説明がわかりにくくなっています。漠然とした「イメージ」として語るのではなく、どの部分が何を表しているのかを明確にするようにしてください。

Comment: 説明不足で申し訳ないです。
ユーザが入力した値を配列に入れ、最後に配列内の値を逆順で出力するプログラムです。

Answer (score 2):

「数字の入力」と「結果の出力」を1つのループにまとめてしまうと当然結果も入力順にしか出力されないでしょう。ループを2つ(数字の入力、結果を逆順に出力)用意する必要があるかと思います。

結果の出力時は配列のサイズでインデックスを`-1`ずつしながらfor文で処理すれば、逆順での出力が出来ると思います。

Comment: コードをきちんと併記していただくことで、大変わかりやすい回答になりそうな気がするのですが。文章だけで表現された質問にはよく「コードを示してください」と言うコメントがつくのはご存知かと思いますが、コードを示すことで改善されるのは回答の場合でも同じだと思います。

Comment: 課題を解かれているという事なのでぜひ質問者ご自身で考えてもらう余地を残したかったのと、私自身がJavaは少しかじった程度なので不正確な情報を載せるよりはロジック（考え方）のみを回答としました。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。私としては自分の意見は表明させていただきましたので、あとはこのコミュニティがどのように判断するかをよく汲み取って最終的にはご自身で判断されれば良い事柄だと思います。ただjavaとはっきり明示された質問に対して「Javaは少しかじった程度‌​なので不正確な情報を載せる」可能性があるとお思いなのでしたら、今回は回答を見送ると言うのも一つの選択肢だったろうと思います。プログラミング言語を明示した質問で「ロジック（考え方）」は同じだからといって、別の言語(今の場合自然言語のみですが)での回答が好ましいとは思えません。

Comment: この回答はこれで十分に解り易いと思いますよ。
もちろんコードがあった方がよい回答もありますが、質問に問題の再現が可能なコードを求めるのとは、別の話です。

Answer (score 1):

`整数を入力してください`と表示してから、10回ユーザーの入力を受け付けて、逆順に表示したいということでしたら、以下のようなコードになると思います。

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // 配列sの初期化
    int[] s = new int[10];
    System.out.println("整数を入力してください");
    // 入力を10回受け付ける
    try (Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            s[i] = scan1.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = s.length; i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.println(s[i - 1]);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

※`scan1`は最後に`close()`を呼び出した方がいいので、`try-with-resources`を使う方がよりいいです(今回のようなmainメソッドを実行するだけの処理であれば、そこまで気にしなくていいですが、場合によってはリソースリークします)。Java6以前であれば、`try-with-resources`が無いので、`finally`句で`scan1.close();`を実行します。

Answer (score 0):

Java のバージョン指定がなければこんなのはいかがでしょうか。

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class SchoolChallenges {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int elementCount = 10;
    int[] s = new int[elementCount];
    System.out.println("整数を入力してください");
    try (Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);) {
        IntStream.range(0, elementCount).forEach(e -> {
            s[e] = scan1.nextInt();
        });

        System.out.println("入力と逆順に出力");
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, elementCount)
                .boxed()
                .mapToInt(i -> s[elementCount - i])
                .forEach(System.out::println);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score -2):

入力用のForの後ろに

```
for (int i = s[i].length; i > 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(s[i-1]);
}
```

で出力すれば、いかがでしょう。

Answer (score -2):

こんな感じかな？
テストはしてません。

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // 配列sの初期化
    int[] s = new int[10];
    // 入力を10回受け付ける
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length-1; i++) {
        System.out.println("整数を入力してください");
        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        s[i] = scan1.nextInt();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length-1; i++) {
        System.out.println(s[(s.length-1) - i]);
    }
}
```